# facing problem in content render in cordova ios app using css -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: css, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps, cordova-ios

Facing dom render issue in cordova ios app with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch css, in config.xml file I already use these property

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

config.xml:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```